# List index out of range in a random generating program

Tags: python, list

I was working on a program that take random
words from a list and combine them into one sentence
but I keep getting an error:

```
  File "test2.py", line 13, in generater
    print list[z+2] ,
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my code:

```
def generater():
    list = ["naji", "gaming", "gameplay", "start", "stuped", "awesome", "fast", "new", "racing", "shoting", "cool", "super"]
    from random import randint 
    x = randint(0,11)
    print list[x] ,
    y = randint(0,11)
    if y == x and y != 0 :
        print list[y-1] ,
    else :
        print list[y] , 
    z = randint(0,11) 
    if z == x or z == y and z < 8 :
        print list[z+2] ,
    elif z == x or z == y and z > 9 :
        print list[z-5]
    else :
        print list[z]
generater()
```

Comment: **Mandatory Warning** - Please do not use `list` as variable name as it shadows the builtin functions

Comment: What do you want your output to be?

Comment: Mandatory Warning  ok thanks

Comment: Katya Handler the output is working but in rare cases it show the error and the outcome is like naji gaming gameplay

Answer (score 2):

Your list contains 12 items, so the valid index range is 0 to 11.

Your rand generator returns a value between 0 and 10.

10 + 2 is more than 11 - so you're trying to access a list index which is off the end of the list.

Comment: oh so x = randint(0,11) is from 0 to 10 ?

Comment: but i have if z < 8

Comment: You also have "z == x" so what happens if they are both 10? Brackets are your friend when you have multiple sub-operations in the same if statement.

Comment: See answer from @Austin below which explains the bracketing issue nicely.

Comment: ok thanks man i red the comment and now i know what i was doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your statement

```
if z == x or z == y and z < 8:
```

Try putting parentheses around (z == x or z == y).  In the event that z == x, your program does not ensure that z < 8.  You can test this by entering

```
if 1 or 1 and 0:
    print('TRUE!')
```

and comparing the output to

```
if (1 or 1) and 0:
    print('TRUE!')
```

In short, you're saying "a or (b and c)," but you want to express "(a or b) and c."

I'm not really sure that I understand the purpose of your program, but as long as you guarantee that your z value is less than 8, you should not get an out of bounds exception.

Comment: i understand now thank you very much for your time man that was really helpful